# Iterate over two arrays using jQuery.each()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I iterate two arrays through a single call to jQuery `.each()`?

Something like this clearly won't work:

```
$.each(arr1, arr2, function(i,v){
  //do something...
});
```

So how can this be done?

Comment: [The docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) show very clearly that you can't do that, and running the code will show very clearly that you can't do that.

Comment: @amnotiam why did you down vote the question? did you see the Jon's answer?

Comment: Because your question shows no basic research effort. Hover your mouse pointer over the down-arrow, and read the popup.

Comment: ...tell you what, I'll edit your question into what you're *actually* asking.

Comment: Sam - Is your intention to iterate through the values of `arr1` first, and then the values of `arr2`? Or do you want to iterate through both in parallel to process the first element from both arrays at once, then the second element from both, etc.?

Comment: @nnnnnn I wanted to insert two arrays in each and then use them in that function directly.

Comment: @Sam: that doesn't answer the question. What do you want? `arr1[0], arr1[1], arr1[2], arr2[0], arr2[1]`? Or `(arr1[0] and arr2[0]), (arr1[1] and arr2[1]), etc`?

Comment: @PPvG this is the code I though, I got two arrays that contains few words each, and using $.each() I wanted to append them in <p> tag arr1 and arr2. content of arr1 first arr2 secondo it's no matter sequence.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An alternative to `.concat` would be double `$.each`:

```
$.each([arr1, arr2], function() {
    $.each(this, function(i, v) {
        // do something
    });
});
```

This could turn out being faster if the arrays contain lots of items.

Comment: What's the benefit of this? Why wouldn't you just have sequential calls instead of nested calls?

Comment: @amnotiam: DRY and also allows you to pass in a variable number of arrays if desired (think `arguments` instead of `[arr1, arr2]`).

Comment: I suppose the variable number of arrays makes sense. As for DRY, I'd probably just use a named function with 2 calls, or make a special `each` that takes multiple arrays, but I do see your point.

Comment: @amnotiam: Sure, all of that is possible. I chose this approach because it's the shortest that also agrees with good practices.

Comment: Btw if performance is a concern one should just use a for loop which will be [much faster](http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-for-loop/73) than any of our solutions because it doesn't require concat or any function calls.

Comment: I'm getting $.each is not a function

Answer (score 8):

> @PPvG this is the code I though, I got two arrays that contains few
>   words each, and using $.each() I wanted to append them in `<p>` tag arr1
>   and arr2. content of arr1 first arr2 secondo it's no matter sequence.
>   – Sam 4 secs ago

You could [`.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) them for the iteration:

```
$.each(arr1.concat(arr2), function(i,v){
  //do something...
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ZG4wq/2/

Comment: Ah, I'd assumed he wanted to iterate separately through two different arrays; I hadn't considered concatenating them. Nice! =)

Comment: @DavidThomas Actually nobody can really know what he actually wants to do :D

Comment: Surely if you want to iterate over two arrays using one `each`, it really means your two arrays should be one array. Hence `concat` seems the obvious thing to do.

Comment: There is that, sure. I'm somewhat ashamed, though, that my answer was basically going to be 'no' (on my earlier-stated assumption)... @Utkanos, possibly. I think it depends what he wants to *do* with the arrays, though.

Comment: There could be at least three different intentions in my mind: 1. iterating as a full concatenated array 2. iterating 2 arrays separately as in jon's answer 3. iterating 2 arrays in parallel in one callback

Comment: If the original index numbers are important, you'd need to add something like `if (i >= arr1.length) i -= arr1.length`

Comment: I was thinking more of sequential iteration, but dealing with the fact that the second array's indices are now offset by `arr1.length`. Sounds like it's probably not an issue here.

Comment: Note:  no arrays are modified by concatenating them.